# How to associate a role to a user in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-roles

On WebForms i used to store the role in FormsAuthenticationTicket userdata, however I tried to implement the same method in mvc 5 and it did not work. For some reason

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

this returns false

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,
    user.Id.ToString(),
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
    model.RememberMe,
    user.Roles.Select(c => c.Nome).FirstOrDefault(),
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
);

// Encrypt the ticket.
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
// Create the cookie.
HttpCookie authenticationCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket); // Name of auth cookie (it's the name specified in web.config) // Hashed ticket
authenticationCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
// Add the cookie to the list for outbound response
Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie);
```

so since this does not work i used instead

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Id.ToString(), model.RememberMe);
```

problem with this is that it does not allow me to have an easy access to the user role so that i can do on a view

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
```

I'm trying to avoid Asp Net Identity because It takes a lot of customization and i don't need all the extra fields nor a password 'cause we authenticate with ldap.

If is there any other option please advice me.

Comment: Please share code of `Application_AuthenticateRequest` in your project or where you set `Context.User` from auth cookie

Comment: I don't have this function implemented yet 'cause i thought it wasn't needed just for authenticating user

Answer (score 0):

Forms authentication doesn't support roles by itself. So you need to set request's `IPrincipal` with roles [manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311495/how-to-implement-role-based-security-with-forms-based-authentication-i). You can do this by "subscribing" on post authenticate event in `Global.asax` and update logged user information. Add the following method inside `MvcApplication` class in `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        //get the forms authentication ticket
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        string userData = authTicket.UserData;
        //here we suppose userData contains roles joined with ","
        string[] roles = userData.Split(',');

        //at this point we already have Context.User set by forms authentication module
        //we don't change it but add roles
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);

        // set new principal with roles
        Context.User = principal;
    }
}
```

Also you need to update login code to create proper `FormsAuthenticationTicket` containing roles joined with ","

```
var roles = user.Roles.Select(c => c.Nome);
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,
    user.Id.ToString(),
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
    model.RememberMe,
    string.Join(",", roles), //or you can serialize complex class as json or whatever
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
);
```

Another option is to [override forms authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.authenticate?view=netframework-4.7.2) by adding `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` method in `Global.asax.cs`

```
public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //get the forms authentication ticket
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                string userData = authTicket.UserData;
                //here we suppose userData contains roles joined with ","
                string[] roles = userData.Split(',');

                //we have to create identity since it's not created yet
                var identity = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);
                var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);

                args.User = principal;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Decrypt method failed.
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpException("Cookieless Forms Authentication is not " +
                                "supported for this application.");
    }
}
```

Both solutions are pretty similar so it's up to you to choose one.